# Unable to send file with PDF( *.pdf) extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to read a file using node's `readFile` method and then send it as response so that user can ***download*** it.

This is my code:

```
async function(req, res, next) {
const query = { id: req.params.id };
// @ts-ignore
const fileURL = await Patient.findOne(query).select('retinaReportURL -_id');

// @ts-ignore
const splittedPath = fileURL.retinaReportURL.split('\\');
const fileName = splittedPath[splittedPath.length-1].split('.')[0] + '.pdf';

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'Invoices', fileName);

fs.readFile(filePath, (err, _data) => {
  if (err) {
    return next(new APIError('Unable to fetch file at the moment please try again later', 500))
  }
  res.send(data);
});
```

}

Now my file path is proper with a valid PDF inside the ***Invoices*** folder.

But the, when the file is getting downloaded, am facing two issues:

1. The ***.pdf*** extension is not there.
2. The ***file name*** by which it's get downloaded is the ***id*** I am passing as request param.

I tried setting a response header to `text/pdf` but no luck.

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: change res.send(data); to res.send(_data); _data you are using right

Comment: What is the issue with `id`?

Comment: @PrakashKarena sorry by mistake I wrote _data, it is actually data in my code.

Comment: @Sohan no issues with id itself as such, just the file which is getting downloaded without extension has the name equal to id and to actual file name as in that folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express has a [helper](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download) for this to make it easy for you,

I assume you have following path,

```
     const fileName = splittedPath[splittedPath.length-1].split('.')[0] + '.pdf';   
     const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'Invoices', fileName);
     app.get('/download', function(req, res)
     {          
      res.download(filePath); // Set file name with its path
     });
```

Comment: Hey thanks @Sohan, your answer helped me and am able to download the file now :) :)